# SQL: calculate a person's age on a certain date, based on date of birth

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of people who visited a certain location during the year of 2017. The goal is to narrow the list down to only people who were within a certain age range when they visited. The query is pretty simple:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    VisitID
    ,VisitDate
    ,PersonID
    ,Age
    ,DateOfBirth

FROM Visit v JOIN Demographics d ON v.PersonID = d.PersonID

WHERE VisitDate BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '12/31/2017'
AND Age BETWEEN 45 AND 75
```

The issue is that the way this query is written, it's pulling in patients who are *currently* within that age range and might not necessarily have been during 2017.

What I'd like to be able to do is add a line of code that calculates how old the person was when they visited by comparing the `VisitDate` and `DateOfBirth` fields. I've written code before to calculate someone's age based on DOB when I didn't have an age field available, but this is a different situation. And so far none of the tutorials or sample code I've found have been in the right context. How might I go about doing this?

Comment: VisitDate - BirthdayDate.

Comment: If you can calculate a person's age based on DOB, all you have to do in this "different situation" is replace `GETDATE()` with `VisitDate`.

Answer (score 0):

-- this should give you what you need in years:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, DateofBirth, DateOfVisit) AS AgeWhenVisit
```

Comment: No it won't.   This will return the number of Jan 1sts that have passed between the DateOfBirth and DateOfVisit.